# Tkinter - Updating Coordinates or Moving a Shape with Variable Value

Tags: python, tkinter, pyserial

I am using Tkinter to visualize sensor data. I have serial data being read, and I want to use it to move a square on the screen.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas
import tkinter
import serial

#GUI
root = Tk()
c = Canvas(root, width=1000, height=50)
c.configure(bg='grey', highlightthickness=0)

#Position Parameters
posX=10
posY=20
lenght=10

subject = c.create_rectangle(posX, posY, posX+lenght, posY+lenght, outline='black', fill='black')

#Serial Data Read
ser = serial.Serial('COM5', baudrate=9600, timeout=0.2)  # open serial port
print(ser.name)                                          # check which port was really used

#Failed Live Visual
while True:
    while (ser.inWaiting()==0):
        pass
    dataPacket=ser.readline()
    dataPacket=str(dataPacket, 'utf-8')                 #Incoming data from arduino into string
    dataPacket=int(dataPacket.strip(' \r\n'))           #Formatting

    posX=dataPacket
    c.coords(subject, posX, posY, posX+lenght, posY+lenght)
    c.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

My issue is: that Tkinter will display but not update the position of the square. I've tried different approaches such as using the c.move() setter, as well as creating a function and calling it with the root.after() command but none seem to work. I don't think this should be so difficult, so that's why I ask.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: It seems you got mostly correct code, but I think you're trying to move `subject` instead of the Canvas window `c` itself, correct? Also, calling `root.mainloop()` will put you into a forever loop and nothing will update. Check out [Tkinter Mainloop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29158220/tkinter-understanding-mainloop)

Comment: @HWW: Nope — the OP is trying to move the `subject` *on* the canvas. It is also untrue that calling `mainloop()` prevents things from updating — quite the contrary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're using `mainloop()` is wrong — it's typically only called once in a `tkinter` application because it is the loop that drives the whole GUI which is event-driven.

One way to work around that limitation in this case would be to use its universal [`after()`](https://tkdocs.com/shipman/universal.html) widget method to schedule periodic checks of the serial port for input.

I've made changes to your code to do this, including adding a <kbd>Start</kbd> button to initiate the periodic polling process. Obviously I couldn't fully test it, but it ought to give you the overall idea.

```
import tkinter as tk
import serial

#GUI
root = tk.Tk()

start_btn = tk.Button(root, text='Start')
start_btn.pack(anchor=tk.NW)

c = tk.Canvas(root, width=1000, height=50)
c.configure(bg='grey', highlightthickness=0)
c.pack()  # ADDED

#Position Parameters
posX=10
posY=20
lenght=10

subject = c.create_rectangle(posX, posY, posX+lenght, posY+lenght, outline='black', fill='black')

#Serial Data Read
ser = serial.Serial('COM5', baudrate=9600, timeout=0.2)
print(ser.name)  # check which port was really used

def check_data():
    if ser.inWaiting():
        dataPacket=ser.readline()
        dataPacket=str(dataPacket, 'utf-8')  #Incoming data from arduino into string
        dataPacket=int(dataPacket.strip(' \r\n'))  #Formatting

        posX=dataPacket
        c.coords(subject, posX, posY, posX+lenght, posY+lenght)
    root.after(250, check_data)  # Check again in 250 ms.

start_btn.config(command=check_data)
root.mainloop()
```